# Obtaining path from ListView to play Audio

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to list all the Music files on the Device as a ListView. And I found this code from a similar question here. It works fine, however I am having trouble in obtaining the exact path of the Music file when the user clicks the item. from the `OnItemClickListener()` method, I am able to obtain the name of the file, but How do I read the absolute path of the file as String? Any help will be appreciated.

```
    public class MusicActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ListView musiclist;
    Cursor musiccursor;
    int music_column_index;
    int count;
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    SharedPreferences musicList;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        init_phone_music_grid();
    }

    private void init_phone_music_grid() {
        System.gc();
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE };
        musiccursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                proj, null, null, null);
        count = musiccursor.getCount();
        musiclist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.sample);
        musiclist.setAdapter(new MusicAdapter(getApplicationContext()));

        musiclist.setOnItemClickListener(musicgridlistener);
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    }

    private OnItemClickListener musicgridlistener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,
                                long id) {
            System.gc();
            music_column_index = musiccursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
            musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
            String filename = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);

            try {
                if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mMediaPlayer.reset();
                }
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(filename);
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                mMediaPlayer.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    };

    public class MusicAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public MusicAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            System.gc();
            TextView tv = new TextView(mContext.getApplicationContext());
            String id = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                music_column_index = musiccursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
                id = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
                music_column_index = musiccursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE);
                musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);
                id += " Size(KB):" + musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
                //tv.setText(id);
            } else
                tv = (TextView) convertView;
            return tv;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA gives you the path whereas MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME gives you the file name.

Comment: okay, If you'd put it as an Answer, it would be much helpful for me and as well for those who refer in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onItemClick` you are using `MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA` which always returns the PATH (or the data stream) of the file.

To get the file name, you need to use, `MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME`.

Just use a `Log` statement to ensure that you have the path correctly and not filename.

```
String filename = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
Log.d("TAG", filename);
```